# Get rgba values of top sliver of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-processing

I'm working on a site that has two types of images.

Image Type 1 has **all** **white** **space** at the top.

Image Type 2 has **at least one pixel of non-white space** at the top.

I am wondering if there is a way to detect if the image has white space anywhere along the first full width of the image (at a height of 1px).

**Image Type 1**

[image]

**Image Type 2**

[image]

Comment: Surely you want to test if the image has at least one *non*-white pixel in the top row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with canvas elements, you can utilize the `.getImageData()` function to get RGBA data from the canvas element. I don't know whether you plan to implement this logic on the server side or in your JS, so I'll just grab an example canvas DOM object to give my example some context.

```
    canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
    // returns array of DOM objects [<canvas width=640 height=480>]
```

Now we select the first image to work with and grab its canvas data

```
    context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    // returns an ImageData object that looks like this:
    // CanvasRenderingContext2D {textBaseline: "alphabetic", textAlign: "start", font: "10px sans-serif", lineDashOffset: 0, miterLimit: 10...}
```

To get the rgba data from a select part of the canvas, set the x ,y coordinates where you wish to start from, the width in px (which, for our example, will be 640), and the height (1 px, per your specs).
 Ex: `context.getImageData(x, y, w, h).data`

```
    rgba = context.getImageData(1, 1, 640, 1).data
    // returns ImageData object from Uint8ClampedArray[2560]
```

Your variable `rgba` stores the R, G, B, A values for every pixel in the first line along the top of your image. That is to say `red = rgba[0]`, `green = rgba[1]`, `blue = rgba[2]`, `alpha = rgba[3]` **for the first pixel**. Then, `rgba[4]` is the red value of the second pixel, and the pattern repeats.

Essentially, you want a variable that stores `nonWhite = false` and changes to true as soon as any one of the R, G, B, A values is not 255. I'll leave the rest of the implementation logic to you, but I hope this is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using ImageMagick to compare pixel RBG values at some coordinates possibly as a way to make this work for you.

Comment: Thanks that's a great suggestion. I'm looking into using the canvas element to get the image data. If that doesn't work out I'll go this route.

Comment: I love IM...its got a ton of uses, functions, and runs on pretty much everything. Enjoy this new found world. LOL!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here?  It doesn't seem like this would be the desirable way to do this.

If you have access to the code, you can just give the images with the white at the top a class="white-top" or something similar and then edit accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The site has over 10,000 images, I cannot go through each one of them by hand and manually give them a class. But thanks for the idea!